# os command is not writing into file

Tags: python

I have below code :

```
 import os, subprocess
 def cfile():
        p = r'/mypath/abc'
        cmd = ["who am i | awk '{print $1}'"]
        if not os.path.exists(p):
                fh = open(p, 'a')
                try:
                     subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=fh)
                finally:
                     fh.close()
 cfile()
```

above code is creating the file called 'folder' but not writing anything. Can you please help me to get to know what is wrong here. I am using python 2.7

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying to output to a file _inside_ `/mypath/folder`?

Comment: Works for me: creates an ordinary file (not a directory) called `folder`, with the date in it.

Comment: @Chris I am creating a file called "folder" under mypath directory and want to append the "date" output into that file

Comment: does the file already exist? this will only do something if the file is not there

Comment: @viveksinha, so you have a file called `folder` (a confusing name for a file) even though you say 'above code is creating the _folder_ called "folder"' (emphasis mine)? `/mypath/folder` isn't an already existing directory?

Comment: @Malvolio : But it is not working for me. It just creating empty file called `folder`

Comment: @nathan.meadows ; I have deleted the file and tried but again its creating only empty file called `folder`

Comment: Stop naming files folder. It gets really confusing really fast.

Comment: @takendarkk can you please have a look on the code now. I have edited the code with new file name. I just want to append this file with my given os command.

Comment: @Chris can you please have a look on the code now. I have edited the code with new file name. I just want to append this file with my given os command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call .wait() on each Popen object in order to be sure that it's finished and then call flush(). Maybe something like this:

```
import os
import subprocess


def cfile():
    p = r'/mypath/abc'
    cmd = ["who am i | awk '{print $1}'"]
    fh = open(p, 'a+')
    try:
        sb = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=fh)
        sb.wait()
        fh.flush()
    finally:
        fh.close()

cfile()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. can you please let me know about the append the same. If I run the same code again if should append the same file from next line onward. I tried `fh = open(p, 'a')` but didn't worked.

Comment: I've modified the solution to create the file if it doesn't exist and append it. Please accept the answer if it works for you.